# How to set target path for content files in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I'm building a Win8 styled app (metro app?) with Visual Studio 2012. I have some asset files I need to deploy with the app (mp3 files). I need them to be in music-folder, say `$(app_path)\music\theme.mp3`. When I set "Content" flag as "True" from properties, the file is copied to as `$(app_path)\theme.mp3`.

**So I'd like to know how can I retain the file structure of the included content files.**

When I go manually relocate the files to their respective folders after finishing compilation in VS2012, it works. But I don't want to manually update my asset files. It poses a risk that I forget to manually update an asset file after it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to care about where your files are located after deploying the app. The path to these files is predetermined by the path in your application project, so if you put files into the Assets folder, you can then access them using:

```cs
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/file.txt"));
Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need to access them with string "music/theme.mp3". Also, there might be an another file named "theme.mp3", under separate folder so they need to remain separated. 

It's a multi-platform, 100MB+ game I'm doing here.

Comment: No matter what kind of application you are creating, if you want to access files in "[app_path]/music/theme.mp3, then you have to use the call I have shown you. You can create some kind of wrapper class for opening files, that will convert your generic paths to system paths with the ms-appx:/// prefix.